# Perl: is possible use variable substitution?

Tags: perl

On bash I did

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%m%y`

echo $DATE
```

on perl I try this one

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
$date=`date +%m%y`;
print "date";
```

And give me..date string and not correct date.

Comment: Did you mean command substitution?  In which case it's `$var = qx( command )`

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487791/how-do-you-read-the-system-time-and-date-in-perl)

Comment: you're printing the literal string "date".  You probably want to print the variable "$date".    And you're probably going to want it with a newline, too, like `print "$date", "\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `localtime()` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
my $date = localtime();
print "$date";
```

Or :

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%m%y`

echo $DATE
```

sample output:

```
1217
```

should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date=`date +%m%y`;
print "$date";
```

sample output:

```
1217
```

use  `print "$date";` instead of `print "date";`